# why is my content shifting to the left after I click a link to a section in my navbar?

Tags: html, css

my website is fine at the start, but when I click a link on my navbar that takes me to a section on the same page, the content shifts to the left.

I have tried many things to correct this issue. can anybody help?

I've tried things such as changing the overflow and margins, I have also deleted the navbar and re-done it as a whole, but the same issue is still there. is there a simple fix to this?

but nothing has worked.

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,600;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,500&display=swap');

  html{
    overflow: scroll;
   
    
 }

  body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }



.header{
  width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(1, 20, 106, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(t-k-9AxFJaNySB8-unsplash.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 10px 8%;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


nav {
  position: relative; 
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex; /* use flexbox to align elements */
  align-items: center; /* center elements vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffffff; /* set background color of navbar */
  height: 7%; /* set height of navbar to 100% */
  width: 100%; /* set width of navbar to 100% */
  position: fixed; /* position navbar at top of page */
  top: 0; /* set top position to 0 */
  left: 0; /* set left position to 0 */
  z-index: 999;
}


nav img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  height: 95%; /* set height of image */
  margin-right: 10px; /* add some spacing between image and links/buttons */
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: none;
}

nav ul  {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.3s ease; /* add transition to color change */
}



nav a:hover{
  
  color: #3e059a;

}

nav button{
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #2c066a;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 35px;
}


.header-content h1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: baseline;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  margin-top: 260px;
  color: white;
 
}

.header-content h2{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: baseline;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}




.wrapper{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10%;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-right: 20%;
  box-shadow: inset;
 

}

.wrapper h1{
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 00;
  color: #3e059a;
  
}

.content-box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 30px;


}


.card{
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 270px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: color 0.6s ease; /* add transition to color change */
}

}

.card i{
  margin: 20px;
  color: #2c066a;
}



.card:hover {
  background-color: #2c066a;
  color: #ffffff;
}


.card h2{
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

card p{
  text-align: center;
}

              
@media(max-width: 991px)
{


.wrapper{
  padding: 25px;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
}


.content-box{
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}


.card{
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

}

/*ABOUT SECTION*/
.about-section {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin-right: 17%;
  margin-top: 10%;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 
}

.about-section .container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
 
}




.about-section h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #2c066a;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif
}

.about-section p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*PROJECT COUNTER*/
.text-center {
  text-align: center;



}

.project-counter-wrap ul{
list-style-type: none;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
margin-right: 10%;
}

.project-counter-wrap ul li{
  width: 33.3%;
height: 100%;
padding: 30px;
transition: 0.2s linear;
font-size: x-large;
margin-right: 10%;
text-align: center;
}

.project-counter-wrap ul li:hover {
  background-color: #2c066a;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}










/*Testimonials*/

.testimonials {

  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #434343;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.inner {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 20px;
}


.border{
  width: 160px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #2c066a;
  margin: 26px auto;

}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col {
  flex: 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
}

.testimonial {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px;
 
}


.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;

}


.stars {
  color: #b1ef08;
}


@media screen and (max-width:960px) {
  .col {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 80%;
  }
}

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: baseline;
  
}

.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.contact-info, .hours {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.directions {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #2c066a;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
 
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,600;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-container">
          <a href="#home"><img src="Budget_Logo-removebg-preview (1).png" alt="logo"></a>
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-us" class="contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
      
  <section id="home">
    <div class="header-content">
      <h1>The Most Trusted <br> Hardware Store</h1>
      <h2>Building stronger communities <br> for over 20 years with quality hardware</h2>
    </div>
  </section>

     

        <section id="services">
          <div class="our-services">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <h1>Our Services</h1>
              <p>For over 20 years, our hardware store has been serving the hardware needs of our customers. We offer a wide range of hardware products and solutions in fields such as:</p>
              <div class="content-box">
                <div class="card">
                  <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h2>Electrical</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio a accusantium consequatur ea nemo, autem unde et voluptates nihil soluta?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                  <i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h2>Plumbing</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio a accusantium consequatur ea nemo, autem unde et voluptates nihil soluta?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                  <i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h2>Paint</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Opt
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        
   


        <section id="about">
          <div class="about-section">
            <section>
              <div class="container">
                <h2>About Us</h2>
                <p>Welcome to Budget Builders Supplies! We are a Hardware company with over 20 years of experience.</p>
                <p>Our mission is to provide you the best service possible when it comes to your hardware needs. We believe in quality and excellent service.</p>
                <p>At Budget Builders Supplies, we strive to be your one stop shop for all your hardware needs.</p>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </section>
    




<div class="count-up-stats">
  <h2 class="text-center">
  </h2>

<div class="project-counter-wrap">

<ul>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p id="number1" class="number">1000+</p>
<span></span>
<p>Happy Customers</p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p id="number1" class="number">20+</p>
<span></span>
<p>Years Experience</p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p id="number1" class="number">500+</p>
<span></span>
<p>Products</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<section id="testimonials">
  <div class="testimonials">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1>Our Testimonials</h1>
      <div class="border"></div>
  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="name">Full name</div>
            <div class="stars">
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic sapiente assumenda numquam corporis maxime reiciendis nostrum quae, molestiae officiis expedita.</p>
  
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="col">
        <div class="testimonial">
          <div class="name">Full name</div>
          <div class="stars">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic sapiente assumenda numquam corporis maxime reiciendis nostrum quae, molestiae officiis expedita.</p>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="name">Full name</div>
        <div class="stars">
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic sapiente assumenda numquam corporis maxime reiciendis nostrum quae, molestiae officiis expedita.</p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>






<section id="contact-us">
  
<footer>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div class="contact-info">
      <h4>Contact Us</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Street Road</li>
        <li>Location</li>
        <li>Phone: 0******</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="directions">
        <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn">Get Directions</a>
      </div>
  
    </div>
    <div class="hours">
      <h4>Opening Hours</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Monday - Friday: 8am - 5pm</li>
        <li>Saturday: 8am - 2pm</li>
        <li>Sunday: Closed</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

</div>




    </div>
</section>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Please provide some of your code. Read **[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** before asking.

Comment: This only seems to happen in the smaller preview window for me, so my guess it's something to do with the size of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easy solution to this problem, which is caused by the object box model, is to set the box-sizing of every element to border-box.

basically you set the width to 100% on the .header class which then looks to the width of its parent element to determine the actual width.
by default a div will use box-sizing: content-box; meaning, its content (not including the padding) will be the same width as its parent. so that will add 8% of the width on both sides.

clicking on an anchor then scrolls it into view to the best position it can so both vertically and horizontally, thats why you see the shift.

the easy fix is to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to every element
and then removing some of the `margin-right` properties that I think you probably added to try and center parts of the website, see the example.

I hope this will be of help to you

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,600;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,500&display=swap');

  /* add this part here */
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  html{
    overflow: scroll;
   
    
 }

  body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }



.header{
  width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(1, 20, 106, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(t-k-9AxFJaNySB8-unsplash.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 10px 8%;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


nav {
  position: relative; 
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex; /* use flexbox to align elements */
  align-items: center; /* center elements vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffffff; /* set background color of navbar */
  height: 7%; /* set height of navbar to 100% */
  width: 100%; /* set width of navbar to 100% */
  position: fixed; /* position navbar at top of page */
  top: 0; /* set top position to 0 */
  left: 0; /* set left position to 0 */
  z-index: 999;
}


nav img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  height: 95%; /* set height of image */
  margin-right: 10px; /* add some spacing between image and links/buttons */
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: none;
}

nav ul  {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.3s ease; /* add transition to color change */
}



nav a:hover{
  
  color: #3e059a;

}

nav button{
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: #2c066a;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 35px;
}


.header-content h1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: baseline;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  margin-top: 260px;
  color: white;
 
}

.header-content h2{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: baseline;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}




.wrapper{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10%;
  height: 50vh;
  /* margin-right: 20%; remove this property */
  box-shadow: inset;
 

}

.wrapper h1{
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 00;
  color: #3e059a;
  
}

.content-box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 30px;


}


.card{
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 270px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: color 0.6s ease; /* add transition to color change */
}

}

.card i{
  margin: 20px;
  color: #2c066a;
}



.card:hover {
  background-color: #2c066a;
  color: #ffffff;
}


.card h2{
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

card p{
  text-align: center;
}

              
@media(max-width: 991px)
{


.wrapper{
  padding: 25px;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
}


.content-box{
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}


.card{
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

}

/*ABOUT SECTION*/
.about-section {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 50px 0;
  /* margin-right: 17%; remove this property */
  margin-top: 10%;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 
}

.about-section .container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
 
}




.about-section h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #2c066a;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif
}

.about-section p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*PROJECT COUNTER*/
.text-center {
  text-align: center;



}

.project-counter-wrap ul{
list-style-type: none;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
/* margin-right: 10%; remove this property */
}

.project-counter-wrap ul li{
  width: 33.3%;
height: 100%;
padding: 30px;
transition: 0.2s linear;
font-size: x-large;
margin-right: 10%;
text-align: center;
}

.project-counter-wrap ul li:hover {
  background-color: #2c066a;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}










/*Testimonials*/

.testimonials {

  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #434343;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-right: 15%; remove this property */
}

.inner {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 20px;
}


.border{
  width: 160px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #2c066a;
  margin: 26px auto;

}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col {
  flex: 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
}

.testimonial {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px;
 
}


.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;

}


.stars {
  color: #b1ef08;
}


@media screen and (max-width:960px) {
  .col {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 80%;
  }
}

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: baseline;
  
}

.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.contact-info, .hours {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.directions {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #2c066a;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
 
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,600;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-container">
          <a href="#home"><img src="Budget_Logo-removebg-preview (1).png" alt="logo"></a>
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-us" class="contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
      
  <section id="home">
    <div class="header-content">
      <h1>The Most Trusted <br> Hardware Store</h1>
      <h2>Building stronger communities <br> for over 20 years with quality hardware</h2>
    </div>
  </section>

     

        <section id="services">
          <div class="our-services">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <h1>Our Services</h1>
              <p>For over 20 years, our hardware store has been serving the hardware needs of our customers. We offer a wide range of hardware products and solutions in fields such as:</p>
              <div class="content-box">
                <div class="card">
                  <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h2>Electrical</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio a accusantium consequatur ea nemo, autem unde et voluptates nihil soluta?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                  <i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h2>Plumbing</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio a accusantium consequatur ea nemo, autem unde et voluptates nihil soluta?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                  <i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h2>Paint</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Opt
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        
   


        <section id="about">
          <div class="about-section">
            <section>
              <div class="container">
                <h2>About Us</h2>
                <p>Welcome to Budget Builders Supplies! We are a Hardware company with over 20 years of experience.</p>
                <p>Our mission is to provide you the best service possible when it comes to your hardware needs. We believe in quality and excellent service.</p>
                <p>At Budget Builders Supplies, we strive to be your one stop shop for all your hardware needs.</p>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </section>
    




<div class="count-up-stats">
  <h2 class="text-center">
  </h2>

<div class="project-counter-wrap">

<ul>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p id="number1" class="number">1000+</p>
<span></span>
<p>Happy Customers</p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p id="number1" class="number">20+</p>
<span></span>
<p>Years Experience</p>
  </li>

  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p id="number1" class="number">500+</p>
<span></span>
<p>Products</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<section id="testimonials">
  <div class="testimonials">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1>Our Testimonials</h1>
      <div class="border"></div>
  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="name">Full name</div>
            <div class="stars">
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic sapiente assumenda numquam corporis maxime reiciendis nostrum quae, molestiae officiis expedita.</p>
  
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="col">
        <div class="testimonial">
          <div class="name">Full name</div>
          <div class="stars">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic sapiente assumenda numquam corporis maxime reiciendis nostrum quae, molestiae officiis expedita.</p>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="name">Full name</div>
        <div class="stars">
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic sapiente assumenda numquam corporis maxime reiciendis nostrum quae, molestiae officiis expedita.</p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>






<section id="contact-us">
  
<footer>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div class="contact-info">
      <h4>Contact Us</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Street Road</li>
        <li>Location</li>
        <li>Phone: 0******</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="directions">
        <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn">Get Directions</a>
      </div>
  
    </div>
    <div class="hours">
      <h4>Opening Hours</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Monday - Friday: 8am - 5pm</li>
        <li>Saturday: 8am - 2pm</li>
        <li>Sunday: Closed</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

</div>




    </div>
</section>

    
  </body>
</html>
```